# attempt to create queryset with filters at runtime does not return rows but SQL looks fine

Tags: django

Django 1.11.5

I am trying to build a query set with a chain of filters at runtime

```
 def query_cache(self, object: ObjectType, filters: List[MutableMapping] = None) -> QuerySet:
    filters = filters or []
    object_name = object.value
    q = Cin7Cache.objects.filter(object_type=f"'{object_name}'")
    for f in filters:
        q = q.filter(**f)
    return q
```

I get a queryset that always evaluates to no rows.
The sql generated is fine. If I run it on postgresql, I get the rows I want

```
SELECT
  "voga_cin7cache"."object_uniqueID",
  "voga_cin7cache"."object_type",
  "voga_cin7cache"."last_modified",
  "voga_cin7cache"."jdata"
FROM "voga_cin7cache"
WHERE ("voga_cin7cache"."object_type" = 'orders' AND ("voga_cin7cache"."jdata" -> 'createdDate') > '"2017-09-09"');
```

I can produce the same SQL with this:

```
result_query = Cin7Cache.objects.filter(object_type='orders').filter(jdata__createdDate__gt='2017-09-09')
```

and in this case, the result_query is not empty. 
The query in this case is:

```
SELECT
  "voga_cin7cache"."object_uniqueID",
  "voga_cin7cache"."object_type",
  "voga_cin7cache"."last_modified",
  "voga_cin7cache"."jdata"
FROM "voga_cin7cache"
WHERE ("voga_cin7cache"."object_type" = orders AND ("voga_cin7cache"."jdata" -> 'createdDate') > '"2017-09-09"')
```

it's not exactly the same: in the where clause, string constant 'orders' is not quoted the second time, but both give the same result set when evaluated in the postgresql console.
WHen I inspect the queryset object, in the non-working case I have `_result_cache = []`
and in the second example, the working one, the query set has `_result_cache=None`
Why is my first query set empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

query string not always the same as running, try it, without single quotation:

```
q = Cin7Cache.objects.filter(object_type=f"{object_name}")
#                                         ^^^         ^^^
```

Comment: ain't that weird. Both queries work when executed in the postgresql console, but your suggestion fixed it in Django. I'll know to treat such details with more care in future. Thank you.